# Python: Appending file outputs from different directories into one overall list

Tags: python, list, io, append

I have n directories (labeled 0 to n), each that has a file (all the files have the same name), from which I want to grab certain lines from each file. I then want to append these grabbed lines together in order (from 0 to n) in a list.

This is my set-up:

```
for i in range(0, nfolders):
    folder = "%02d" % i
    os.system("cd " + folder)

    myFile = open("myOutputFile", "r")
    lines = myFile.readlines()
    firstLine = float(lines[0])

    #I then write a loop to store the next 5 lines in a list using append and call this list nextLines
```

My question is, is there an easy way to append firstLine from all the directories into one list (that my function returns), as well as append nextLines from all the directories into one list (again, that my function returns)?

I know there is the extend function, would I loop over that here (because let's say I have nfolders = 300, making it hard to manually add things together)?

Thanks!

Comment: @jpp - I was getting to an answer for you but you deleted your question - want to continue in chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170642/wwii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems to deal with. `os.system` changes the working directory of the subshell invoke (and then immediately exit), but not the directory of this running script. Use `os.chdir` for that. Or, far better, just add the path to the file name and use that.

You don't need to read the entire file to get its first line, `.readline` or the `next()` function does that for you. Finally, just append to a list.

```
my_list = []

for i in range(0, nfolders):
    filename = "%02d/MyOutputFile" % i
    with open(filename) as myFile:
        firstLine = float(next(myFile))
        my_list.append(firstLine)
```

*UPDATE*

Suppose you want `4 + i` lines from each file. You could tighten this up with

```
my_list = []

for i in range(0, nfolders):
    filename = "%02d/MyOutputFile" % i
    with open(filename) as myFile:
        my_list += (next(myFile) for _ in range(4+i))
```

Note that we only use `range` to count iterations and don't care about its value so we use the variable `_` as a quick visual queue that the value is not needed.

Comment: Thanks! However, what would I do for if I wanted "nextLines" which are a set of lines in myFile? Basically, I want to grab anywhere from 4 to 18 lines (the number of lines to grab is are incremented by i) in myFile from each directory. Would I do this similarly of appending them within the with open command, and then appending all the lists together?

Comment: You could get multiple lines by `firstLines = [next(myFile) for dummy in range(4, 4+i)]` to get a list of lines. (I just guessed on how you want to do the range). Then you could either do `my_list.append(firstLines)` to make a list of lists, or `my_list.extend(firstLines)` to add the new lines to the list.

Comment: Thanks! So if you want to grab multiple lines in each directory and then append them all together in order to make one large list, would it make more sense to use my_list.extend rather than my_list.append?

Comment: Yes, extend adds the individual items from one list to another. Another way to do `extend` is with `+=`. So, after the open you could do `my_list += (next(myFile) for _ in range(4, 4+i))` and skip that intermediate `firstLine` list completely.

Comment: I see - thank you for your help and clear explanations :)!